R: How to use cumsum() based on specified ranks in a data frame (and not on the order of values)?
Considering I have a data frame like this wherein ranks are specified under each column. (This implies that row 1 under column A ranks third, then row 2 ranks first, and row 3 ranks second. Under column B, row 1 ranks first, row 2 ranks second, and row 3 ranks third.)
df <- data.frame("A" = c(3, 1, 2),
                 "B" = c(1, 2, 3))

What I want to do is create a code where the data frame will be replaced by this logic called "cumulative reciprocals", based on the specified ranks in the data frame.

first rank = 1/(1/1) = 1.0000
second rank = 1/(1/1 + 1/2) = 0.6667
third rank = 1/(1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3) = 0.5454

As I will deal with thousands of ranks in my actual data set, the logic is basically like this: nth rank = 1/(1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 ... + ... 1/n)
In my sample data frame, I would want the ranks to be replaced with the calculated cumulative reciprocals, so it should look something like this.
expected.df <- data.frame("A" = c(0.5454, 1.0000, 0.6667),
                          "B" = c(1.0000, 0.6667, 0.5454))

I am currently using cumsum() with the code below, but I am not getting the expected results under column A. So, I think I might be missing something.
df.current <- apply(df, 2, function(x) 1 /cumsum(1 / rank(x)))

I assume cumsum() might operate based on the order of the values based on the sequence of the ranks under each column, and not actually the ranks?

Not the fastest option but you can go with something like this with the tidyverse :
### Packages
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

### Data
df=data.frame("A" = c(3, 1, 2),
              "B" = c(1, 2, 3))

### Applying a function (with a map operation) on each column
 expected.df=df %>%
 mutate(across(everything(),function(z){map(z,~1/sum(1/1:.x))}))

Output :
          A         B
1 0.5454545         1
2         1 0.6666667
3 0.6666667 0.5454545

